# Как вырезать кусок из фона, который задан цветом?

Tags: html, css, svg

Имеется первый блок с `bg-изображение`. Слоем выше находится следующий-второй блок, но с уже `bg` в виде `#fff`, т.е. первый блок с фоном `#fff` перекрывает собой второй блок с `bg-изображение`.

Имеется-ли возможно вырезать часть фона второго блока так, чтобы мы через это `отверстие` увидели изображение первого блока?

Скрин-пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно реализовать через canvas

Comment: А можно пример?

Comment: нужно начертить фигуру линиями, задать ее как маску и вставить изображение, все будет реализовано в одном блоке canvas и написано на js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно через `clip-path`, в [статье](https://css-tricks.com/cutting-inner-part-element-using-clip-path/) Аны Тюдор описано более подробно.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 610px;
  height: 565px;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper > div {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}

.first-layer {
  background: url(https://i2.wp.com/digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/flickr/5661878892_15fba42846_o.jpg?resize=610%2C565&ssl=1);
  position: absolute;
}

.second-layer {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  clip-path: polygon(
  /* points of the outer triangle going counterclockwise */
  285px 150px, 83px 33px, 83px 267px, 
  
  /* return to the first point of the outer triangle */
  285px 150px, 
  
  /* points of the inner triangle going clockwise */
  258px 150px, 96px 244px, 96px 56px, 
  
  /* return to the first point of the inner triangle */
  258px 150px
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first-layer"></div>
  <div class="second-layer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Нашли решение:
https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipping">
      <polygon points="98.4999978 153.75..."/> // ваша маска
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

-

```
.item {
  clip-path: url(#clipping);
}
```

Comment: Поддерживаю и вдогонку [примерчик набросал](https://jsfiddle.net/fr9w11p5/)